# My app keeps stopping, attaching the important logcat message?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Pic for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLT9.jpg)Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.vaibh.thinkingfastandslow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)

```
thecharactersoftheStory = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2a);
  thecharactersoftheStory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TheCharactersoftheStory.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In my XML file I have

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button2a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1. The Characters of the Story" />
```

Comment: Could you post your whole code of `Activity`, or Else mention in which line of logcat error redirecting.

Comment: Do you have this button in MainActivity' s layout xml?

Comment: error is in second line, and I do not have this button in MainActivity's layout xml

Comment: Confirm that, `button2a` belongs to `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`

Comment: it belongs to activity_two_systems.xml (other layout than MainActivity's layout) layout, I have added a screenshot to make it more clear,

Comment: It seems that `button2a` in `activity_two_systems.xml` layout missing in MainActivity. For more clarification you can share your `MainActivity`

Comment: I have found the other way to do the same thing, thanks though